# Extract maximum date string in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to crawl a web site and fetch data from a page. The page has some strings as below.From this data, I need to find the maximum date from the string and store it into table. How can i achieve this?

```
a = "January 13-17, 2014"
b = " Mar. 19-22, 2012 and April 10-12, 2012"
c = " Nov. 30 - Dec. 3, 2009"
d = "October 29-November 2, 2012"
```

and i need output as

```
January 17, 2014
April 12, 2012
Dec 3, 2009
November 2,2012
```

Comment: why you choose `April 12, 2012` from `" Mar. 19-22, 2012 and April 10-12, 2012"`

Comment: @Kasra Because that's the latest date that the string involves. (April comes after March and 22nd is highest). To OP: I don't think that regex is the right tool here.

Comment: thanks @Jerry , if its so HOW he think it could be done with regex ???

Comment: @Kasra Unless there's a definite pattern that the OP can define, you can't do it with regex, at least not alone, because regex doesn't understand how dates work in how one comes before the other. You could use a bunch of lookaheads for the rules, but it'll be pretty ugly.

Comment: @Jerry thanks for explain , and because of that im wondering about using regex here !

Comment: @Kasra I'm not saying i need to bring this result using regex, but im saying is there a way i can achieve this either regex or some other kind of..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find answer for this question.

```
import re

a = "January 13-17, 2014"
b = " Mar. 19-22, 2012 and April 10-12, 2012"
c = " Nov. 30 - Dec. 3, 2009"
d = "October 29-November 2, 2012"

format1_regex = re.compile(r"""\s*((?:January|Jan|February|Feb|March|Mar|April|Apr|May|June|Jun|Ju(?:l|1)y|Ju(?:l|1)|August|Aug|September|Sept|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec).?\S*)\s*\d{1,2},\s*\d{4}""",re.I)


date_values = [a,b,c,d]
result = ""
for date_val in date_values:
    splitted = date_val.split("-")
    if len(splitted) > 1:
        check_format = format1_regex.search(splitted[-1])
        if check_format:
            #print check_format.group()
            result = check_format.group()
        else:
            #print re.sub(r'\d{1,2}[\s\S]-','',date_val)
            result = re.sub(r'\d{1,2}[\s\S]-','',date_val)
    if "and" in result:
         result = result.split("and")[-1]
    elif "&" in result:
        result = result.split("&")[-1]

    print result 

// output
January 17, 2014
 April 12, 2012
 Dec. 3, 2009
November 2, 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you looke at[dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) - it has a generic parser for date values that will return `datetime` objects. From there you can simply output / compare them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

For those example values you can use such regexp:

```
([\w\.]+) \d*-*(\d+), (\d{4})$
```

But it is based on fact that string ends with year (group 3), preceded by maximum day (group 2), preceded by maximum month (group 1).

Such assumption may not work for dates in other format or in other order.